# RedisTemplate hashvalue serializer to use for nested object with multiple types

Tags: json, serialization, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to use Redis to store some cache data for my entity, which has different types of fields inside, for example,

```
public class Job {
    private String id;
    private Date createTime; //Long
    private String submitterName;
    private JobDefinition jobDef;  //Another class
}
```

There are more fields and due to the fact that several fields are updated more frequently than others, I decided to save this `job` as a Hashmap in Redis with each field as a key. Here the nested object like `jobDef` is not important so I used `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` as `hashValueSerializer` for `RedisTemplate` and the `jobDef` obj will just be serialized as a long JSON string, which is totally fine in my case.

But I don't know how can I effectively deserialize the whole `job` object back from Redis. The type I set to deserializer is like `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Map.class)` but it complains when deserializing String keys and values.

So is this an invalid usage with `RedisTemplate` or how should I configure my serializer for it?

EDIT:
Adding more code details,

```
    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate; //Here I'm using a String template as I need to use the same redisTemplate for some key-value/list operations too

    Map jobHash= new ObjectMapper().convertValue(job, Map.class);

    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Map.class));

    redisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll("job:"+job.getId(), jobHash); //After this the job hash shows up in Redis as I expected, while the jobDef member is serialized and saved as a JSON string

    Map jobMap = redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries("job:" + job.getId()); //But this won't work as it'll throw exception complaining cannot deserialize a String value to Map. But when I set Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(String.class) it throws exception that cannot resolve the byte code
```

2nd EDIT:

If using `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` as HashValueSerializer in `RedisTemplate` then the deserialization works fine, however the downside for using this one is the value stored in Redis is not the same human readable string value as when using `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`.

Comment: Please share a bit more context how you actually persist and load values to/from the Redis `HASH`. Ideally add configuration of `RedisTemplate` in terms of used `RedisSerializer` and the code for storing/reading using `HashOperations` and the representation of your data in Redis.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I should have left more specific usage code. Just added. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` does not include mapping information into the actual hash structure.
The resulting Redis HASH results in something like:

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall job:1
1) "id"
2) "\"1\""
3) "createTime"
4) "1455778716799"
5) "submitterName"
6) "\"Jon Snow\""
7) "jobDef"
8) "{\"def\":\"nightwatch\"}"
```

The `ObjectMapper` produces a `LinkedHashMap` for the `JobDefinition` entry which fails to deserialize as the type is unknown.

Using the `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` includes type information so the resulting Redis HASH looks like this:

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall job:1
1) "id"
2) "\"1\""
...
7) "jobDef"
8) "{\"@class\":\"java.util.LinkedHashMap\",\"def\":\"nightwatch\"}"
```

This allows to deserialize values correctly.

Another approach would be to **NOT** use a specific `HashValueSerializer` but instead use a `DecoratingStringHashMapper` along with the `StringRedisTemplate`.

```java
DecoratingStringHashMapper mapper = new DecoratingStringHashMapper<Job>(
  new JacksonHashMapper<Job>(Job.class));

template.opsForHash().putAll("job:" + job.id, mapper.toHash(job));
Map jobMap = template.opsForHash().entries("job:" + job.id);
```

The `DecoratingStringHashMapper` will produce a Redis Hash as follows:

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall job:1
1) "id"
2) "1"
3) "createTime"
4) "1455780810643"
5) "submitterName"
6) "Jon Snow"
7) "jobDef"
8) "{def=nightwatch}"
```

Unfortunately there is no `Jackson2HashMapper`. Please vote for [DATAREDIS-423](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-423) and help us prioritize.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Since I'm running on Spring-data-redis 1.4.2 seems to me `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` is not available yet. The second approach almost works like magic except the hash converted has createTime missing, is there any problem converting non-string value? I noticed my original line of `Map jobHash= new ObjectMapper().convertValue(job, Map.class);` uses a different ObjectMapper (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#ObjectMapper()`) and it can generate date value in hash.

Comment: The `JacksonHashMapper` still uses the `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`. You can try passing in your own configuration of that one - I did not have trouble serializing `java.util.Date` values using it with the defaults. The code for `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` is on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java), so you might just want to copy it into your project in case you cannot upgrade to a more recent version.